# textedit setError

Tags: android, android-edittext, parseint

```
public void validateData() {  
    EditText txtdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdate);  
    Integer value = Integer.parseInt(txtdate.getText().toString());  
    if (txtdate.getText().toString().length()==0)  
        txtdate.setError("field cannot be empty please enter the correct values");  
    else if (value>31 ||value<1)  
        txtdate.setError("Date must be from 1 to 31");  
    else {  
        Intent intentuserinput=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserEpenses.class);  
        startActivity(intentuserinput);  
    }
}
```

I have this code that only works if I have only/any one "if" with else but not working with both if. The message I get on emulator is `myApp stopped working` my debugger is normal.

Comment: When is the `validateData()` method being called?

Comment: "myApp stopped working" doesn't mean anything other than your app crashed. What does the logcat say?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and called the `validateData()` method when the focus from the field gets changed. The method you have written is fine except one thing:

```
Integer value = Integer.parseInt(txtdate.getText().toString());
```

If the text inputted by the user is not an integer, it'll cause the app to crash. You could do two things to prevent it

1. In your layout xml file, make the input type as number:

   ```
   android:inputType="textPassword|number"
   ```
2. Surround the `parseInt` with try-catch:

   ```
   try {    
       Integer value = Integer.parseInt(txtdate.getText().toString());  
   } Catch (Exception e) {
       txtdate.setError("Please enter a valid date (1-31)");
   }
   ```

That way, your app won't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would write the code something like this. Mostly because it seems like you are trying to parse an int out of a string that is potentially empty or not even a number, which throws an exception, and you don't catch that.

```
public void validateData() {  
    String errorMsg = "";
    EditText txtdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtdate);  
    String s = txtdate.getText().toString();  

    if (s.length() == 0) {  
        errorMsg = "field cannot be empty please enter the correct values";
    }

    Integer value = null;

    try {    
        value = Integer.parseInt(s);  
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errorMsg = "Please enter a valid date (1-31)";
    }

    if (value == null || value > 31 || value < 1) {  
        errorMsg = "Date must be from 1 to 31";
    }  

    if (!errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
        txtdate.setError(errorMsg);
    } else {
        Intent intentuserinput=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserEpenses.class);  
        startActivity(intentuserinput);  
    }
}
```